# How can i get the package component XML as TBB output

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to get the default Package Component XML as the TBB Output. I am using the below code :

```
 public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
    {

        XmlDocument packagebasexml = new XmlDocument();
        packagebasexml.LoadXml(package.GetByName("Component"));         

        package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, package.CreateXmlDocumentItem(ContentType.Xml,packagebasexml));

     }
```

but i am not able to get, kindly give any suggestion/changes.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you trying to get the Package Item xml or the xml of the actual component (They are slightly different)

Comment: i need to get package item xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following .Net TBB should copy the Component Package Item XML to the Template output:

```cs
using System.Xml;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly;

namespace SDLTridion.Templating
{
    [TcmTemplateTitle("Get Component Input as Output")]
    class GetComponentInputAsOutput: ITemplate
    {
        public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
        {
            Item componentItem = package.GetByName(Package.ComponentName);
            XmlDocument componentItemXml = componentItem.GetAsXmlDocument();
            Item componentItemXmlAsString = package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, componentItemXml.OuterXml);
            package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, componentItemXmlAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David , i got the output

Comment: By the way, If you wanted this information for debugging purposes, it's not necessary to set it as your template output. You can easily see it in the Item View window of SDL Tridion Template Builder when you click on the item named "Component" in the Package window

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with **.Content** property. Also may I know what you want to achieve by pushing XML to package.

```
public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
{

    XmlDocument packagebasexml = new XmlDocument();
    packagebasexml.LoadXml(package.GetByName("Component").Content.OuterXml);         

    package.PushItem(Package.OutputName, package.CreateXmlDocumentItem(ContentType.Xml,packagebasexml));

 }
```

Another way to get full xml

```
Item m_XmlInput = m_Package.GetByName(package.GetByName("Component"));
XmlTextReader input = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(m_XmlInput.GetAsString()));
```

Comment: "content.outerxml" will not give us the full component xml,what we are getting in package. it will give only <content></content>. I need to get full xml of the component.